Compute Buffer of bytes to RWTexture2D float4 in Compute Shader
I'm struggling with a Compute Shader whose purpose is to take a byte array of rgba values and write them to a render texture. I'm passing in ints (as I don't believe I can use byte itself) to the compute buffer (colorBuffer), when I cast them to floats, I get nonsensical values (-23494 or 0.0000934) but when I setup the testBuffer as int and fill the buffer I get the correct values in the 0 - 255 range so I believe the byte values in the compute shader are fine until I try to cast or convert to float in the shader. If I convert the byte array to a float array on the CPU and then pass in floats, it works as expected.
Is there a proper way to read in a byte (or int) array into a compute shader and convert to float values to write to a texture?
Buffer<int> colorBuffer;
RWBuffer<float> testBuffer;
RWTexture2D<float4> colorTexture;
 
float rgbWidth;
float rgbHeight;
 
[numthreads(8,8,1)]
void RGBProcessing (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    const int index = int(id.y * rgbWidth + id.x);
    const int blue = colorBuffer[(index) * 4];
    const int green = colorBuffer[(index) * 4 + 1];
    const int red = colorBuffer[(index) * 4 + 2];
   
    colorTexture[id.xy] = float4(float(red / (float)255), float(green / (float) 255), float(blue / (float) 255), alpha);
    testBuffer[index] = float(blue);
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // C# dispatch
rgbBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(rgbImageWidth * rgbImageHeight * sizeof(int) * 4, sizeof(int));
testBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(rgbImageWidth * rgbImageHeight * sizeof(float) * 4, sizeof(float));
rgbBuffer.SetData(_rgbBytes); // rgbBytes is a byte[]
testBuffer.SetData(debugFloats); // debugFloats is a float[] and int[] works correctly
rgbProcessing.SetTexture(0, ColorTexture, _intermediateRGBTexture);
rgbProcessing.SetBuffer(0, ColorBuffer, rgbBuffer);
rgbProcessing.SetBuffer(0, TestBuffer, testBuffer);
rgbProcessing.SetFloat(RGBWidth, rgbImageWidth);
rgbProcessing.SetFloat(RGBHeight, rgbImageHeight);
rgbProcessing.Dispatch(0, rgbImageWidth / 8, rgbImageHeight / 8, 1);
 
testBuffer.GetData(debugFloats);

